# How to set md-select panel to be open by default

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am using angular4 with Redux and angular material to design my web page.
I am trying to set the md-select panel to be open.
example scenario: click button dispatches an action to open the select panel opens to dispaly all options.

I am using redux actions to manipulate my components state. So basically I need to fire an action to set the select to open.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to update your question to reflect what you want defaulted to open. Do you want the state to default this controller to open? And then this component to read that state upon initialization? Having your state default to open is different than just have this select default to open. Be specific about what you're asking for.

Comment: @Meeker I updated the description to explain my use case.

Comment: Your example scenario suggests that the panel is initially closed till someone clicks something, which is the opposite of defaulted to open. So now this is more confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the Material2 example as starting point for this answer. Here is how you can do that:

> Give an id to your panel, e.g. `mySelect`

```
<md-select placeholder="Favorite food" #mySelect>
  <md-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
    {{ food.viewValue }}
  </md-option>
</md-select>
```

> ... then change your component class:

```
import {Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MdSelect} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
})
export class SelectOverviewExample implements AfterViewInit {
  foods = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];

  @ViewChild('mySelect') mySelect: MdSelect;

  ngAfterViewInit(){
      this.mySelect.open();
  }
}
```

---

Plunker link here: [**PLUNKER DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/H9HDvB9JQNwHpJD0fvMq?p=preview)

Comment: It is really helpful thanks. But I am using redux actions to manipulate my component state. So basically I need to fire an action to set  the select to open.

Comment: Not mentioned in your post :)

Answer (score 1):

This example shows you how to subscribe to state so that the drop down will be whatever the current state is. So change `initialState` to be true if you want it initially open.

There is a button that dispatches the toggle state action to open the drop down.

This can be modified to toggle or create separate open/close buttons or whatever you need.

**state.ts**

```
export interface AppState {
  isDropDownOpen: boolean
}

const initialState: AppState = {
  isDropDownOpen: false;
};

export function appReducer(
  state: AppState = initialState,
  action: any
): AppState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'toggleSelect': {
      state.isDropDownOpen = action.payload
      return state;
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

**my-component.ts**

```
import {Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MdSelect} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <md-select placeholder="Favorite food" #mySelect>
      <md-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
        {{ food.viewValue }}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
    <button (click)="openSelect()"> Open Select </button>
`,
})
export class SelectOverviewExample implements AfterViewInit {
  foods = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];

  @ViewChild('mySelect') mySelect: MdSelect;

  controller( private store: Store<AppState>){
    store.select(state => state.isDropDownOpen).subscribe(isDropDownOpen => {
      if(isDropDownOpen){
        this.mySelect.open()
      } else {
        this.mySelect.close()
      }
    })
  }

  openSelect(){
    this.store.dispatch({ type: toggleSelect, payload: true })
  }

}
```